# Receive a TCP SYN packet without sending a SYNACK response

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I want to be able to receive SYN packets from a client, but not send back a SYNACK response. I have tried a few things. If you use raw sockets, it is possible to receive the full packet but linux kernel seems to automatically send back a FINACK packet. I found out that this was because I did not have a service actually listening to the port I was monitoring. My next step was to bind a socket to the port I was interested in, and use the listen() syscall to listen to that port, along with the raw socket. This approach results in the kernel automatically sending back a SYNACK rather than a FINACK. Is there anyway to receive a raw packet, and not send back an automated response? It seems that raw sockets can only snoop on packets, rather than actually handle them. I have also tried using a UDP server socket to listen to the target port, but I am still sending back an automatic FINACK.

Comment: You would need to insert yourself between IP and TCP in the network stack. It is the TCP process receiving the segment from IP that sends the response.

Comment: Does that mean I should receive ip packets instead of tcp? Is there a way to drop the packet after receiving but before sending to the tcp layer?

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to write kernel code that modifies the TCP driver. This is all handled automatically in the network stack.

Comment: Finally! An excuse to write kernel code.  Can a module do this work?

Comment: @yemista Did you ever succeed in doing this?

Comment: @Behrooz so it worked on a local network but not across the internet.  I think the right way to do this is with Linux internal firewall module

Comment: @yemista Interesting.
I have since found that there is a kernel api (TCP_REPAIR) that allows setting the connection to any(connected, disconnected, ...) state without sending a packet. Haven't had the chance to try it yet.